# Desireable form of container for transporting cans of beer in luggage

Tags: air-travel, luggage, food-and-drink, fragile-luggage

I was intending to bring some beer back home in my check-in luggage. From reading some of the previous questions on StackExchange, I know that transporting beer in glass bottles is safe and practical, but since aluminium cans are much lighter than glass bottles, I was wondering if there is a more suitable container for taking them in luggage. In my luggage there is just clothes, some print material and a laptop.

Will aluminium cans be more prone to damage in the process of luggage handling, or in the cabin environment with lower pressure? Is there something I need to pay extra attention to when packing them in my luggage?

Comment: I prefer to transport beer in the stomach cavity.  Sits well with me and isn't prone to damage.

Comment: I'd say cans are about the best way. Maybe some kind of polyurethane bladder would be *the* best, but that's only going to work for flat beer, and isn't exactly a standard packaging for beer.

Comment: Carry-on is probably the best way, but unfortunately this isn't really possible anymore.

Comment: Tangential, but laptop batteries are typically not allowed in checked luggage.  They have the potential to burst into flame when subjected to unusual temperatures/pressures, which is double-plus ungood in an unmonitored cargo hold.

Comment: @easymoden00b Depends. Stomach cavity is prone to damage when near full/over capacity. When the container fails, it would similarly affect clothes...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One consideration is protecting the bottle, and other posters have suggested socks, clothes, or bubble wrap for this - perfectly sensible. However, you may also be interested in protecting the contents of your suitcase in the event of a leak. I'm more experienced transporting wine than beer, but the same principles apply: pressure changes may cause liquids to leak.

My standard procedure is to put the item in a sturdy plastic bag (hotel laundry bag is often a good source), roll that up and tape it up, then wrap the whole in cling film / saran wrap (this is your waterproofing), then wrap that up in bubble wrap. This has protected me against both leaks and (once) a broken bottle - no idea what force was applied to the case to break a bottle through bubble wrap, but not a drop of wine escaped. I now ensure the bottles are right in the middle of the case.

Comment: +1 and I'd add a few layers of clothing, e.g. a t-shirt wrapped around the bottle for additional shock-proofing.

Comment: Will the normal household cling film do the trick? Or to protect other items only the cling film of packaging grade will work?

Comment: @Edison I just use normal household cling film (saran wrap). It's only providing waterproofing; the strength comes from the other layers.

Answer (score 20):

Socks, put the beers in socks and/or roll them in your own cloths.

On a side note, I would not put a laptop in check-in luggage if possible. Take it with you as a carry-on.

Comment: Put the padded beers in ziploc bags so if they do rupture it doesn't ruin your other stuff

Answer (score 7):

Socks as @max said are a great idea.

Tons Plastic bubble wrap ( that's what i did).  all my guiness bottles and cans sustained a high atmospheric flight due to a storm from dublin to barcelona without breaking, loosing gas , or opening alone, and had a good taste afterwards.

Plus, if something breaks inside a big bubble wrap ball, nothing else will soak.

Also, as @max said, laptop as carry on if you don't want to find a surprise.

Comment: A well-shaken can let loose inside bubble wrap will let quite a lot of liquid out unless you tape up every join securely

Comment: unless it's sticky bubble wrap. i buy it in rolls of 5-10 metres , very useful for packing stuff, very cheap too.

Comment: but if you are away on vacation you do not want to carry a bulky quantity of bubble wrap with you just in case you bring back beer (or wine).

Comment: I once heard that Guiness doesn't travel well, but I think it was about kegs for pubs.

Comment: Yeah kegs must be at a especial bar of pressure, that's why they travel mostly by land and sea

Comment: @Max There are actually specifically things sold for wine, often referred to as wine diapers, which are basically stackable, sealable bubble wrap in wine-bottle shape (functioning as both insulation of the bottle from drops *and* insulation of the rest of the suitcase in case of breaking anyway), which we *do* bring a few of with us in case, if we think we might bring wine back home. You could probably repurpose them for a couple cans of beer per, if you stuffed the interstitials with socks.

Answer (score -1):

We did this once for 2h flight with friends. We simply put them into the luggage, with a simple with a knot bag around it in case of rupture. One of the side benefits was that the beer was nice and cold after the flight.